# How can I combine these 2 functions without going over the 50,000 character limit?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to simply replace anytime I referenced the cell into the actual function inside of the referred cell. This normally works in every single other function
I've done this with, but in this case, it's a big function and it gets referred to many times. This causes it to go over the 50,000 character limit for functions and this method no longer applies.

check out this spreadsheet to see the functions I'm talking about:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RFA8s68TSQI2jQSOQm2_Ma776vC1LUQn7JP9tg-gZ1g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide an explanation of how those values are determined? And what do you mean by "combine output 1 and output 2"? Also, the sheet is view-only...

Comment: make a copy of it. by combine I mean I want to only have one output, the second output relies on the first output. basically output 1 is just step 1 of the formula and output 2 is step 2

Comment: clearly replacing E3 in F3 is not an option since as you said it goes above the characters limit. That means we have to approach this in a different way but I can't help if I don't know the logic behind those values.

Comment: can't you just make a copy to see them?

Comment: all I'm asking you is to provide a brief explanation of the logic behind your output as I don't have the time to break down a 3600 characters formula.

Comment: oh sorry, do you want me to explain p.1 or p.2?

Comment: both. You have the inputs 22.6d and 2.00, how do these produce 3.7667d?

Comment: p.1 is simply input1/(2.5*input2+input1) but able to accept letters as numbers

Comment: p.2 is converting p.1 back into letters

Comment: > "be able to accept letters as numbers" 

how are letters converted to numbers? Can you create a table in the sheet?

Comment: a table as in what numbers turn into what letters and vice versa?

Comment: yes. If you make the sheet editable we can talk directly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the formula:

`=index(fixed(regexextract(A3,"[\d.]+")*product(10^vlookup(regexextract(A3,regexreplace(A3,"([A-Za-z])","($1)")),split(flatten(regexextract(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),regexreplace(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),"(.)","($1)"))&"❄️"&sequence(13,1,3,3)),"❄️"),2,0))/(2.5*B3+1)/10^sumproduct((exact(index(split(flatten(regexextract(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),regexreplace(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),"(.)","($1)"))&"❄️"&sequence(13,1,3,3)),"❄️"),,1),C3))*(index(split(flatten(regexextract(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),regexreplace(flatten(split("Kk,Mm,Bb,Tt,q,Q,s,S,Oo,Nn,d,Uu,D",",")),"(.)","($1)"))&"❄️"&sequence(13,1,3,3)),"❄️"),,2))),D3)&C3)`

I couldn't find an efficient way to automatically convert back to the best unit because we are dealing with huge numbers that get turned to scientific notation preventing us from easily getting the actual length of the number. For this reason, I added a cell (C3) where you can specify the unit you want. I also added another cell (D3) where you can specify the amount of decimal places you want to display.
[image]

Comment: although the point was to make less boxes, I can use what you made and turn it into what I wanted so thank you very much!

Comment: you can get rid of D3 and hardcode it directly in the formula.

Comment: I can do it for both, I more-so know how to do it for c3 than d3 but I'd rather figure it out than ask about it. thank you very much btw

Comment: nvm I misunderstood what d3 was for

Comment: i made the solution out of what you posted, check out the sheet again z. (it's roughly 47.5k characters lol.) I think you'd appreciate it